# Stuck in a query. Even don't know what should it be called... is it a co-related sub query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Look at the query carefully first before answering it.

I get the error in the sub query where i access the column from outer query. 
at **C1.C_ID = a.C_ID**

```
SELECT
        COL_ANY,
        COL_ANY1,
        COL_ANY2

FROM A  a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.B_ID = b.B_ID
WHERE
 a.C_ID =  (SELECT  c.C_ID FROM C c 
    INNER JOIN C C1 ON C1.C_ID = a.C_ID)
```

Comment: I think replacing everything after WHERE with a.C_ID is not null has no effect over the result.

Comment: invalid identifier a.C_ID. Sub query can't access the column a.C_ID from outer query.

Comment: You need to join `C` and `C1` at some way, but instead of that `C1` joined with `a` ... Give  a meaningfull aliases to tables instead of single letters to avoid such errors.

Comment: yes i want to join C and C1 but i want to join the C1 on C_ID=a.CID... there is no such error of aliases...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're trying to do (it would be helpful if you explained this in your question) - you want to get all rows from `A` with a C_ID that exists in `C` ?

In which case you could do:

```
SELECT
    COL_ANY,
    COL_ANY1,
    COL_ANY2
FROM A  a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.B_ID = b.B_ID
WHERE
 a.C_ID IN (SELECT c.C_ID FROM C)
```

or probably better, just join to `C` as well:

```
SELECT
    COL_ANY,
    COL_ANY1,
    COL_ANY2
FROM A  a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.B_ID = b.B_ID
INNER JOIN C b ON a.C_ID = C.C_ID
```

Comment: but i also want to get all C_ID from C where C_ID=a.C_ID. look into inner query.

Comment: Both of my examples give you exactly that.